# How can i get rotate UIImageView with changable angle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics

I have created one `UIImageView`
Here's code

```
capView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kARROW_CAP_NAME]];
capView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kARROW_H, kARROW_H);
[self addSubview:capView];
```

Now I have two points which I need to move around View, So, they are Updating..

PointA, PointB

I got the angle between them:

```
CGFloat angleBetweenPoints(CGPoint first, CGPoint second) 
{
    CGFloat height = second.y - first.y;
    CGFloat width = first.x - second.x;
    CGFloat rads = atan(height/width);
    return RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rads);
}
```

When I apply this angle to my UIImageView, it continuously change,

My used code here:

```
capView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(arrowAngle);
```

or

```
capView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, arrowAngle);
```

Arrow Angle is the value of above function which i write above..

Please take a look and help me.

Comment: what do u mean by  ' It continuously change'. have you written transformation statement in a timer?

Comment: No, when i drag any single point of which return angle between them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, So simple..

But still no one give me answer..

```
capView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(M_PI_2 - arrowAngle))
```

And RADINAS is macro define here,

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)
```

Thanks to all who be a part of it..